# Titanium studio not finding android 2.2 even though it's installed

Tags: android, sdk, installation, titanium

I'm having an extremely difficult day today. I've installed the latest version on Titanium Studio and the android sdk. When I want to create a new project in TS I don't have android stupport. So I try and set it up manually by pointing TS to the sdk install directory which is (C:\Android\android-sdk-r18).

I then get this error:

> Titanium SDK Home: The Desktop-SDK root
>   path'C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\sdk\win32' is not a
>   directory. Android SDK Home: Exception, No android-8 or android2.2 in
>   the Android SDK. Unexpected character(T) at position 0;

This is absolute rubbish because I most def have android 2.2 right up to android 4.0.3 installed in my sdk.

PS - I'm running Windows 7 64bit, with java 1.7 32bit installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just spent a couple days wrestling with this problem.  The issue is with the latest version of the mobile sdk that you've installed.  Titanium Studio actually uses the following script to validate the Android SDK path in the configuration window:

MAC path looks like this:

/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/***sdk_version_number_here***/android/avd.py

Based on your post, your path is probably something like:

C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\***sdk_version_number_here***\android\avd.py

If you browse to the folder and look for that script, it's probably missing.  We just deleted that version of the sdk (for us it was 2.0.1.GA2). Then went to Help -> Check for Updates to reinstall the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/136858/titanium-sdk-home-the-desktop-sdkaniumsdkwin32-is-not-a-directory#answer-238698) may be useful to you. Also I think you need to use 32 bit java `1.6` as titanium studio does not work with java 1.7

Basically you need to put titanium-sdk at C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32 folder.

Either you can manually download compressed file from [here](http://cloud2.appcelerator.net/production/2.0.1.GA2.17042012152423/mobilesdk-2.0.1.GA2-win32.zip), uncompress the file (mobilesdk and module folders) to `C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\`

or you need to do `Titanium Studio->help->check for titanium sdk update`.

I would prefer you go with `"check for titanium sdk update"`

hope this helps

Comment: I tried what you suggested above. Unfortunately it didn't sort out the problem. I gave you an up-vote anyways. Since everything is up to date now and I have the right version of java installed. Pitty it didn't solve my problem though.

Comment: did u download the mobilesdk-2.0.1.GA2-win32.zip file from the url above? if yes, then extract it to C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\

Comment: Yep I did that also. I've come a bit closer though. Titanium does now see the Android SDK and packages but I'm still sitting with one error: "An error was detected with the SDK's configuration. Reason: 'C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\sdk\win32' is not a directory". This is somewhat a different error. i'll open a new thread for this...

Comment: can you please mention the paths for "titanium sdk home" and "android sdk home" that you have set under "titanium studio->windows->preferences->titanium studio->titanium"?

Comment: Titanium SDK Home: C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium.    Android SDK Home: C:\Android\android-sdk-r18.

Comment: i hope there is "SDK Manager.exe" in C:\Android\android-sdk-r18 directly.

Comment: Yes there is :-) The Android problem is back again. I didn't touch anything! Do you personally work on Titanium Studio? Because my impression is starting to think that it's complete rubish. Do you know of any other Javascript platform to develop mobile apps? I'm sick of struggling with this crap.

Comment: Yes I am using titanium studio. I know its difficult to start working on it because it does not show exact error message and instead it says something meaningless. I used Sencha Touch earlier for mobile app development but it was having some issues like slow start, not native code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to `Help->Install Titanium sdk from url`

2.add this url - http://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/release-download?token=b4pNB8S6

3.Let it download (around 48 MB)

4.Restart Titanium Studio. It should all work fine.There shouldnt be any error about desktop sdk path now.

For missing android sdk error :-

`Make sure you have android sdk version 2.2 installed`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for error:

- Titanium SDK Home: The Desktop-SDK root path'C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\sdk\win32' is not a directory or in Mac
- [Titanium SDK Home] The Desktop-SDK root path
  /Library/Application Support/Titanium/sdk/osx' is not a directory

  1. Download your SDK [Mac/Win] from [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/09/introducing-titanium-desktop-sdk-1-2-release-candidate-4.html)
  2. Unzip and put all folders (modules should be combined) to location of Titanium:

     - for Win path is 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\'
     - for Mac path is '/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/'
  3. Voila.